# I am losing column names when accessing a table via get(j)

Tags: r, data.table

For a data.table query, I get either a named column, or an unnamed one ("V1") depending on how I access it. Does anybody know why and how I can still get a named column when using a programmatically passed column name to access it?

```
    name <- "Column.Title"

    DT[, .(Column.Title)]
    # gives:
    #    Column.Title
    # 1: 100

    DT[, .(get(name))]
    # gives:
    #    V1
    # 1: 100
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can use `DT[, mget(name)]` also for multiple column names in "name"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `with = FALSE`

```
DT[, name, with = FALSE]
```

Or with `..`

```
DT[, ..name]
```

Or specify it in `.SDcols`

```
DT[, .SD, .SDcols = name]
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast! And it's already the solution, thank you! How could I miss the `..` notation...